# How do I get notified when NSSpeechSynthesizer finished speaking?

Tags: xamarin, text-to-speech, xamarin.mac

I am using `Xamarin.Mac`, and I am writing a text to speech project.

In `Xamarin.Mac`, the class `NSSpeechSynthesizer` does not provide the event `DidFinishSpeaking`. May I know how I can get notified when the speaking is finished?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`NSSpeechSynthesizer` provides a `delegate` in the form of an interface (`INSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate`) that contains the `DidFinishSpeaking` method:

```
public partial class ViewController : NSViewController, INSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate
{
    ~~~~~~

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var s = new NSSpeechSynthesizer(NSSpeechSynthesizer.DefaultVoice)
        {
            Delegate = this
        };
        s.StartSpeakingString("StackOverflow");
    }

    [Export("speechSynthesizer:didFinishSpeaking:")]
    public void DidFinishSpeaking(NSSpeechSynthesizer sender, bool finishedSpeaking)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Done speaking");
    }

    ~~~~~~
}
```